# MySQL ORDER BY not working using 2-word alias

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, alias

```
SELECT
  u.user_id AS 'ID'
, u.username AS 'Username' 
, u.lastname AS 'Last Name' 
, r.rolename AS 'Role' 
FROM user AS u , role AS r  
ORDER BY Last Name
```

This query is not working. But it works when I try to use the `ORDER BY` followed by 1 word. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You query is doing a CROSS JOIN as you do not specify the join conditions. Hence is will return every single possible combination of the records on the user and role tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL engine doesn't know `Last Name`, but it knows `lastname`, so your query should be:

```
SELECT u.user_id AS 'ID' , u.username AS 'Username' , u.lastname AS 'Last Name' ,
r.rolename AS 'Role' FROM user AS u , role AS r ORDER BY u.lastname
```

Or if you want to use `'Last Name'` you should use it enclosed in 2 `'`, because it is 2 words separated by space.

Comment: Ok, if you want use Last Name you should use it like this 'Last Name'

Comment: Reason it works with ID, Role and Username is that they would be valid column names without the quotes around them. Last Name has a space hence needs to be surrounded with delimiters.

Comment: Not `'` (apostrophe), but `\`` (backtick) must be used in MySQL for 2-word alias in `ORDER BY`.